# How to play mp3 music file from uri end with extension .mp4 in WinRT apps

Tags: c#, xaml, mp3, winrt-xaml, mp4

I have web Uri like: http://123.456.769/music.mp4.

While I set MediaElement's Source with that uri, I got a media failed exception ("Could not open that video"),

But I can play this file, if download and rename it to "music.mp3";

How can play it without download?

Comment: Is the source file actually an mp3 or an mp4 file? mp4 files are not music files and almost everything will attempt to load it as a video. If it truly is an mp3, then the file extension should be corrected so the correct playing process will play it.

Comment: yes, source file is mp3 file, but I can't change it, because music server not my own

Answer (score 1):

Create a Stream via the Uri. You can use the `RandomAccessStreamReference` class.

```
var uriStreamReference = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(myUri);
var uriStream = await uriStreamReference.OpenAsync();
```

You can then set the source of your `MediaElement` via the `SetSource` method. You can also set the MIME type for mp4 audio.

```
myMediaElement.SetSource(uriStream, "audio/mp4");
```

If it's an mp3 whose filename is simply an mp4, switch to `audio/mpeg`.

Hope this helps and happy coding!